# Separate concatenated Case When statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there is a way to separate this statement and create a sentence like One, Two - or Two, Three. The separator must not work unless there is something following.

```
case when d1.code = 'X' then 'One' else '' end +
case when d2.Code = 'Y' then 'Two' else '' end +
case when d3.code = 'Z' then 'Three' else '' end as PlzHelp
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a recent version of SQL Server, use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', CASE WHEN d1.code = 'X' THEN 'One' END,
                      CASE WHEN d2.Code = 'Y' THEN 'Two' END,
                      CASE WHEN d3.code = 'Z' THEN 'Three' END) AS PlzHelp
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an older version, you could go for something like this

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN d1.code = 'X' THEN ', One'   ELSE '' END
                      +CASE WHEN d2.Code = 'Y' THEN ', Two'   ELSE '' END
                      +CASE WHEN d3.code = 'Z' THEN ', Three' ELSE '' END
                      +'  ' ,3 ,17)) AS PlzHelp
```